# Reference each title in array of titles

Tags: puppet

With Puppet 2.7.11, I need to create several symbolic links from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/bin` and want to be clever:

```
class containing_class {
    file { [ "/usr/local/bin/job", "/usr/local/bin/jstart",
             "/usr/local/bin/jstop", "/usr/local/bin/jsub"]:
        ensure => link,
        target => regsubst(name, "^/usr/local/bin/", "/usr/bin/")
    }
```

However, `name` causes the links' targets to be `name`, `$name` and `$title` use `containing_class` (!) instead and `$path` the value of `$PATH`.

How can I reference the title/path of the individual file in the call?

Comment: You'd need to be in a defined type for `$title` to work how you're expecting - would that be acceptable?

Comment: @ShaneMadden For this specific use case it would probably be disproportionate; copy & paste would probably be easier.  Care to write your solution -- even if it's not working for my use case -- as an answer though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this might not be what you want, but should work:

```
class containing_class {
    define bin_link {
        file { $title:
            ensure => link,
            target => regsubst($title, "^/usr/local/bin/", "/usr/bin/"),
        }
    }
    bin_link { [ "/usr/local/bin/job", "/usr/local/bin/jstart",
                 "/usr/local/bin/jstop", "/usr/local/bin/jsub"]: }
}
```

Comment: It does work indeed, and I will probably use it when there are more than four files to deal with :-).  Thanks!